# Problem with endless tabbing when importing a python file into vim in google cloud

Tags: python, vim, tabs, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am just getting starting with clouds and having a problem with importing/pasting code into vim (in my VM instance in the compute engine). Every new row is tabbed on time more than the row before, [image: as shown in this picture]. Any idea why this happens?

Grateful for any answer!